# Javascript/jQuery: start "blinking" on first AJAX call success, stop on next

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a "blinking" effect as to signal to the user that a background task is occurring: the button hovers/blinks while the Ajax call is being made, and comes back to full opacity when it's done. However, I'm getting weird and inconsistent results. The closest I got is this:

```
// globals are bad, I know
should_blink = true

// right before Ajax call
should_blink('#my-button', do_animate);


// inside Ajax call success
do_animate = false;
should_blink('#my-button', do_animate);

function should_blink(selector, do_animate) {
    console.log(do_animate);
    if (do_animate) {
    $(selector).fadeOut(300, function () {
        $(this).fadeIn(300, function () {
            should_blink(this, do_animate);
            })})}
            else {
                $(this).fadeIn(300);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting weird and inconsistent results : what are they and could you please create a code snippet of you problem

Comment: @aravind - the div actually doesn’t fade in, the console prints a series of ‘true’ values and then false and then true (indefinitely)

Comment: i guess you code having a callback hell..could you please create a snippet

Comment: `should_blink()` -  this is a recursive function but it doesn't have a closing condition as recursive function is supposed to have, that's why looping indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue in a much simpler way by using CSS `blink`:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  from {opacity: 1.0;}
  to {opacity: 0.0;}
}
.blink{
    text-decoration: blink;
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

I then use jquery's respective `AddClass` and `RemoveClass` to trigger the animations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is `$(this).fadeIn(300);`, the `$(this)` is not contained in a selected element...

```
if (do_animate) {
  $(selector).fadeOut(300, function () {
    $(this).fadeIn(300, function () {
      should_blink(this, do_animate);
    });
  });
} else {
  // $(this).fadeIn(300);
  $(selector).fadeIn(300);
}
```